# Stripe checkout API: setting a statement descriptor for subscriptions

Tags: stripe-payments

In Stripe Checkout, we can easily modify the statement descriptor for a single payment intent (charge) in Stripe API using the code below.

```
Session::create([
    'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
    'success_url' => 'https://example.com/success',
    'cancel_url' => 'https://example.com/cancel',
    'line_items' => [...],
    'mode' => 'payment',
    'payment_intent_data' => [
        'statement_descriptor' => $statementDescriptor,
    ]
]);
```

How can we set a custom statement descriptor when using mode `subscription`??

```
Session::create([
    'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
    'success_url' => 'https://example.com/success',
    'cancel_url' => 'https://example.com/cancel',
    'line_items' => [...],
    'mode' => 'subscription',
    'subscription_data' => [ ??? ]
]);
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to set up statement descriptor on Checkout Session in `subscription` mode. The default statement descriptor will be set to the first subscription item’s product’s statement_descriptor.

Alternatively, you may [create subscription using API](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/build-subscriptions?ui=elements) and update [statement descriptor](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/update#update_invoice-statement_descriptor) on the invoice every time when the invoice is still in `draft` state. The update Invoice request has to be made every billing cycle when an invoice is created.

Comment: This is the kind of details that feel cryptic in the Stripe API.

Likewise, on stripe.checkout.Session.create, payment_intent_data supports a `receipt_email` parameter, but subscription_data does not.